# Отображение текста на девайсах HUAWEI с правой стороны

Tags: java, android, xml, rtl

Почему-то текст именно на девайсах HUAWEI отображается справа, я уже всё перерыл, гугл молчит, английский стековерфлоу тоже.
Application Tag:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".ShopApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    />
```

TextView XML

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_value"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="start"
   android:text="23.000.000.097"
   android:textColor="@color/background"
   android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

Application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_red_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Ставлю gravity start - текст справа, end -текст слева.
Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой?

UPD:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_value"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="start"
   android:text="23.000.000.097"
   android:textColor="@color/background"
   android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

То есть из, за того, что TextView больше текста и gravity end -текст слева

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/hMLNX5)

Comment: Ссылка на английский топик, Дабы избежать лишних вопросов
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371538/trouble-with-text-alignment-on-huawei-devices

Comment: Покажите родитель `layout`, у вашего `TextView` не задан `layout_gravity`, а ширина `wrap_content`. Так невозможно определить будет ли текст позиционироваться справа или слева, потому что сама длина вью элемента в пределах длины содержимого. Установите ширину у вашего `TextView` `match_parent`, а потом позиционируйте в нем текст с помощью `gravity`, если у вас на одной строке два `TextView` то первому задайте `android:layout_gravity="start"` второму `android:layout_gravity="end"` при этом ширина у обоих должна быть `wrap_content`. Еще можете попробовать заменить `start/end` на `left/right`